# Benefits of adding aquarium salt to freshwater juvenile discus tank

Tags: aquarium, fish, community-aquarium

One of my friends suggested that I add "API Aquarium Salt" to my 40 gallon freshwater tank to promote good health for the fish. He mentioned it will kill some bacteria that can attack freshwater fish. I'm worried about how my fish will react to this salt being added to the water.

Will this really be beneficial for my juvenile discus?

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no-one has answered this already. Since you're keeping discus fish, my first recommendation is to seek out a dedicated discus forum - plenty to be found with an internet search. Regarding using Aquarium Salt in your tank, I would only do so if you have a parasitic problem or for nitrite poisoning. Maintaining quality water parameters is always more preferable than any kind of medication - even salt.

Answer (score 1):

Anything I have read about discus has said they prefer soft, acidic water - minimum dissolved salts. I second the suggestion of finding a discus chat room / bulletin board.